# How do you remove a certain set of characters, so that it does not duplicate, from an array of strings in Javascript or AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

Say I have an array as such;

```
$scope.array = ["ABC", "ABCDEF", "ABCDEFGHI", "ABCAFGKJA"];
```

is it possible to return it as such?;

```
$scope.array = ["ABC", "DEF", "GHI", "KJ"];
```

sorry if the question is not too clear, still learning the terminologies. cheers!

Comment: Is it always sorted in this way, or can it ["ABCDEFGHI", "ZCVZ", "ABC", "ABCDEF"] as well? Are the duplicates always positioned on the start of the string, or can they be in the middle of the strings as well?

Comment: @OriDrori hey there, thanks for the quick response! anyways, it is sequential, as i am trying to break up a statement like this ((A|B|C)&D);
and it returns it based on the evaluation as such ["A|B|C" , "(A|B|C)&D"];
so what i would want in return is; ["A|B|C", "()&D"]; something like this.

Comment: @UdhayanNair - Taking your comments from other answers into account I have updated my answer using your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A version with [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) and [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), for inner and outer loop.

In the outer loop, it is necessary to iterate the actual reduced items, to reduce the actual string.

```js
function getParts(r, a) {
    r.push(r.reduce(function (q, b) {
        return q.replace(b, '');
    }, a));
    return r;
}

console.log(["ABC", "ABCDEF", "ABCDEFGHI"].reduce(getParts, []));
console.log(["A|B|C", "(A|B|C)&D"].reduce(getParts, []));
console.log(["abc", "abch", "def", "abchdefg"].reduce(getParts, []));
console.log(["A|B|C", "(A|B|C)&D", "E|F|G", "((A|B|C)&D)&(E|F|G)"].reduce(getParts, []));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: When using `["ABC", "ABCDAAEF", "ABCDEFGHI"]` it doesn't remove the other `A` characters. I assume that is what OP wants, given the phrasing to remove duplicate characters and not strings. I had the same problem in my solution. - Though I could be wrong given the reply of OP in his comments.

Comment: without more examples, it's just speculation.

Comment: hey there @Fran ! yeah, what you said is right, i want every occurrence of A to be removed, i think i can work on Nina's method, cause it seems quite neat.

Comment: thanks for the response @NinaScholz ! but its as what Fran said, sorry for the lack of clarity;
so it'll be like this :
$scope.array = ["abc", "abcda", "bcbaghj", "efa"];
should return 
$scope.array = ["abc", "d", "ghj", "ef"];

Comment: thanks for the quick update, @NinaScholz ! ok so now here's the thing, it works if its something like 
$scope.array = ["abc", "abcdef", "abcadfaad"];
but if its like 
$scope.array = ["abc", "abch", "def", "abchdefg"];
its returns this: ["abc", "h", "def", "abchg"];
is it possible to make it return this,
["abc", "h", "def", g"] ?

Comment: like if i console.log(["A|B|C", "(A|B|C)&D", E|F|G, ((A|B|C)&D)&(E|F|G)"].map(getParts));
i get 
["A|B|C", "()&D", "E|F|G", "((A|B|C)&D)&()"];
Whereas what i want is;
["A|B|C", "()&D", "E|F|G", "(())&()"];

do you think that it's better to use regex here or something?

Answer (score 0):

Taking your comments into account from other answers, if you want to remove all occurrences of the characters no matter where in the string they are positioned, the following should work.

Yes, there is most likely a way more efficient way of writing this but the below seems to work.

```js
var x = ["A|B|C", "(A|B|C)&D", "E|F|G", "((A|B|C)&D)&(E|F|G)"];
// Expected Result  ["A|B|C", "D", "E|F|G", ""]
var existingChars = [];
var reg;

for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < existingChars.length; j++) {
    existingChars[j] = existingChars[j].replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');
    reg = new RegExp(existingChars[j], 'g');
    x[i] = x[i].replace(reg,'').replace(/[&\)\(]+/g, '');
  }
  
  existingChars = existingChars.concat(x[i].split(''));
}

console.log(x);
```

Comment: thanks for the response so quickly again @Fran , really i appreciate it.
here's the problem now though, not sure why, but i keep getting this error when i try to run your bit, Error: unterminated parenthetical, is it due to the regex?

Comment: works like a charm as well @Fran , thanks so much for the quick response! :D

Comment: @UdhayanNair I'm not sure, I had issues when your input had special characters in it but ones I escape them before replacing the characters it was fine.

Comment: to be honest, i would need it to exclude the special characters later on, so that instead of it displaying as 
["A|B|C", "()&D", "E|F|G", "(())()"],
it displays ["A|B|C", "D", "E|F|G", ""],
I honestly wonder why i took up doing a promotion validator as a project now haha, but it's fun for it to be challenging.

Comment: For completeness `["A|B|C", "D", "E|F|G", ""]` is now the result when input is `["A|B|C", "(A|B|C)&D", "E|F|G", "((A|B|C)&D)&(E|F|G)"]`

Comment: sorry for troubling you once again, but what if i just want that instance to disappear? like say it's  ["A|B|C", "(A|B|C)&D", "E|F|G", "(((A|B|C)&D)&(E|F|G) & A & B)"] and i want the output to be
["A|B|C", "D", "E|F|G", "AB"]; is it possible? 
so it removes A|B|C, D, E|F|G. this whole thing is looping my mind now. hahah. @Fran

Comment: @UdhayanNair Ones you start looking at multiple custom patterns regex gets to confusing for me :) but yes, it should be possible to create a pattern where any letters with `&` in between are joined while others are replaced/removed as duplicates. I just don't know myself how to :)

Comment: Fair enough! Thanks again so much @Fran for the assistance! :D

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 
var $scope = { array: ["ABC", "ABCDEF", "ABCDEFGHI"] };
var result = $scope.array.map(function (a, i, b) {
        return a.indexOf(b[i - 1]) ? a : a.slice(b[i - 1].length - a.length);
    });

$('#results').text(result);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="results"></div>
```

Comment: hey there @Idoshhh thanks for the response! this is similar to Nina's code that she previously wrote earlier, above. it's pretty neat, but not exactly what i want, partly due to my lack of explaining. thanks though!